# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'session' in 'field list' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting a strange error! I did not create any field named 'session' in ***database*** and there is no such field in ***model*** named 'session'. I used ***SoftDeletes()*** in the model but whenever I am trying to insert data I get an error with this message:

**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'session' in 'field list'**

Here is the model:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Article extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'headline', 'summary', 'body', 'status', 'cover_image', 'image_caption', 'image_credit', 'cover_video', 'video_caption', 'video_credit', 'category', 'meta', 'tags',
]; 

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

}
```

Here is the database:
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNYXs.jpg)

Here is the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $article = new Article;
    $article->user_id = $request->user_id;   
    $article->headline = $request->headline;  
    $article->summary = $request->summary;   
    $article->body = $request->body;   
    $article->status = $request->status;   
    $article->session = $request->session;
    $article->category = $request->category;
    $article->meta = $request->meta;
    $article->tags = $request->tags;


    //dd($request->session());


    $article->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'Article Successfully Added!');
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are referencing a `session` column when attempting to save: `$article->session = $request->session;`

Comment: If you didn't take field then why are you writing `$article->session = $request->session;` in your controller?

Comment: you didn't have any `session` coulmn in your database

Comment: @MirukuSheki - The OP started by saying that...

Comment: Thanks! It worked but this error was showing previously without this line. Then I put it to see what happens if I try to store 'session'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi because in your store function you do this

```
 $article->session = $request->session;
```

delete this and it s work

Comment: Thanks! It worked but this error was showing previously without this line. Then I put it to see what happens if I try to store 'session'.

Comment: hi your welcom i think that this feild 'session 'exist in other place in your editor searche in all the project for 'session' try this

Comment: you re welcom ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't put `$request->session` in `$article->session` especially if you save it through eloquent `->save()`
Learn more about Laravel Eloquent here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Comment: Thanks! It worked but this error was showing previously without this line. Then I put it to see what happens if I try to store 'session'